# Shiny server and install packages

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server, r-package

Hello I´m started with shiny server and with linux.I have some question about this.
First if i want use package like rodbc or shinydashboard in shiny -server where i must install them?
Second how can I install them?

Comment: If you have already installed `R` on your `linux ubuntu` server then you just type R in terminal which will open R environment in your terminal. After that you can install any R package, for example `install.packages("shinydashboard")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to install packages to Shiny, you'll want to install them via the CRAN repository.  To do that, we'll start by opening the R console:

`$ R`

Once you're in the R console, installation from CRAN is very simple.

`> install.packages("packagename")`

and if you are looking for more CRAN packages to install (or what to confirm the package name) you can find it on the [R project website](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html)